# android WebView cookies expires when exit app

Tags: android, cookies, webview

As the `CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();` [is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager)  Itried to maintain cookies forever in my application using new command
[flush()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#flush()) :

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
            CookieManager.getInstance().acceptCookie();
            CookieManager.getInstance().acceptThirdPartyCookies(webview);
            CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        }
        // and more settings for webview
   }
```

But every time I open the app it seems that previous cookies were expired. Do those options help preserving cookies? And Should I put them in `onPageFinished`?

Besides I have to say that the cookies are working fine on the target website and are set to live for 100 days. Also minSdkVersion is 21 and targetSdkVersion is 29.

Answer (score 0):

Using PersistentCookieJar — persistent and good for encapsulating the Cookies within the App itself. please check[this](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar)

every time APP plan to launch Webview, the cookies will need to be copied from the PersistentCookieJar to the CookieManager.